# File Explorer always empty in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, file

The File Explorer view in Eclipse used to work, so that while an app was running, I could see and manage files in its memory. But since a couple of days the File Explorer is always completely empty. Both for the emulator and for physical devices.

Any suggestions about how to make this feature work again are very welcome!

Comment: do you have any device selected in the "Devices", when the file explorer is empty.

Comment: Where do I find that menu with "devices"? Nothing is clickable in File Explorer, except to minimize its window etc.

Comment: the place from where you opened the "File Explorer", you will find another menu called "Devices". Goto DDMS, then on lower left corner you will find a icon saying "show view as fast view", click it you will find "Devices"

Comment: Ah, yes, "Devices" in DDMS, I know that one. And yes, now it works. It must have been unselected. Great thanks for quick solution!!!

Comment: Doesn't work, I selected the device and file explorer is still empty. Also doesn't work when I select the running app under the device.

Answer (score 10):

just to make it an answer :)

Select the device in the Devices, it will show the files in the file explorer for that device.

Answer (score 1):

The easier solution of it is to goto the taskmanager. Kill the adb process. Eclipse will start giving connection error with the AVD. Now, run your android virtual device again from the eclipse. Thats it. Its Done. You'll see the files in the file explorer in a sec.:)

Answer (score 0):

It is the matter of the file 'toolbox' in /system/bin/, and lack a file 'ls' is that directiory. You can try in below steps:

1.Use an emulator and pull the file toolbox down and put it in your SD card of the phone.

2.Use "adb shell" and replace toolbox in your phone.

3.Set the permission to 'rwxr-xr-x' if necessary.

4.Then copy a file which is linked to toolbox and rename it to 'ls'(This step I use Root Explorer).

5.Restart adb you can discover that the ddms file explorer is not empty again~

Hope I can help you :)

refer to:  http://www.miui.com/thread-268003-1-1.html