# DDMS showing empty file explorer for online emulator

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, emulation, ddms

I am facing this problem from many day,i searched a lot but not found any convenient answer.

Whenever I start a emulator ,after some time when I see DDMS its show the emulator online but its  File Explorer is show nothing . Its visible again when I restart my emulator again or restart Eclipse .but I dont want this ,I want a quick solution.

One more thing I have already set the device timeout to a higher value but its also not working. Here is Screen Shot of my DDMS .Can anyone have a Quick Solution.Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: You can refer to : I answered the question in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9443860/file-explorer-always-empty-in-eclipse/18808631#18808631

Answer (score 27):

I see that the question was posted back in 2013 so there was probably some other problem at play then... but for those seeing this problem today it's probably because of an issue with Emulators targeting Android 24 or 25. Currently it appears that the Android Device Monitor is not able to display the file contents for Emulators targeting Android 24 or 25. It is however able to show file contents for Emulators targeting Android 23. Try launching an Emulator targeting Android 23 and you should see the Emulator's file contents in the File Explorer tab as expected.

I've created an Android bug report [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=229628).

**Edit:** a couple more bug reports about this [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=225049) and [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=226984).

Comment: Tip: When on the emulator, I go in the notifications & try to change `USB connected for debugging` to being for `file transfers`, it always removes the file permission and never saves that setting. But if I just start the emulator and never touch that screen, it auto-grants file transfer permissions (on version 23) even though the notification will say `USB connected for debugging`.

Comment: Rock Lee, how does your comment relate to my answer? I'm never seen the Android Emulator to have a `USB connected for debugging` notification btw.

Comment: I mean the emulated android device's notifications. If you drag down from the top of the screen, it will show the notifications for the device. One notification says "USB debugging connected, Tap for more options." When  I clicked on it, it says "Use USB to" and some options are "Charge this device", "Supply power", "Transfer files", "Transfer photos (PTP)", and "Use device as MIDI". When I clicked "Transfer files", for some reason it doesn't save the setting, and removes file transfer permissions.

Comment: I was using android emulator targeting 24. its was not showing file explorer. I created new emulator with targeting 23 API level and it worked. This should be the correct answer so for :)

Answer (score 3):

from command prompt move to \sdk\platform-tools\

and type

```
adb kill-server
```

and then

```
adb start-server
```

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by the following steps: 1. Open windows task manager and kill adb.exe process. 2. Close eclipse and restart it. Then it works.

Hope it helps.

But i cant understand about online emulators. Do you mean virtual devices ?

Comment: Yes u can say it virtual device.                                      and about ur solution...i dont want to restart my eclipse or emulator ..its time consuming .i want a faster way .

Comment: I am not sure, ddms connects only the sdk integrated in eclipse. we cant migrate virtual device to eclipse. if you can kindly share with me. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you have to do is first launch the emulator ,then go the Window->show view -> other -> Android -> devices.Then you will be able to select the device that is online,now go the file explorer,which which will show all the files related to that specific device.Another point need to be noted here is ,the files in the file explorer varies from device to device

Comment: this post does not answer why the file explorer shows up empty!

Answer (score -2):

You have to keep the device selected in the devices view.